# How to change mediaType for a view in Controller - Spring MVC

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, content-negotiation

I have implemented Content Negotiation using http://spring.io/blog/2013/05/11/content-negotiation-using-spring-mvc.

I have a controller ProviderController & all the views in that controller are appended with .action in web.xml

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>provider</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.action</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

and if any view needs to be rendered in html, I use the format query parameter (ex: renderHtml.action?format=html). How do I render a page in another format without using the format query parameter?

P.S : I am using spring 3.0. I can't use produces annotation.

Thanks

Edit :

viewresolver configuration in provider-servlet.xml

```
<bean id="viewResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver">
    <property name="favorParameter" value="true" />
    <property name="parameterName" value="format" />
    <property name="ignoreAcceptHeader" value="true" />
    <property name="defaultContentType" value="application/json" />
    <property name="favorPathExtension" value="false" />
    <property name="mediaTypes">
        <map>
            <entry key="json" value="application/json" />
            <entry key="html" value="text/html" />
        </map>
    </property>

    <property name="viewResolvers">
        <list>
            <bean
                class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
                <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/provider/" />
                <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
            </bean>
        </list>
    </property>

    <property name="defaultViews">
        <list>
            <bean
                class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.json.MappingJacksonJsonView" />
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

web.xml :

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>provider</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>\WEB-INF\provider-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
        <param-value>org.eclipse.virgo.web.dm.ServerOsgiBundleXmlWebApplicationContext</param-value>
    </init-param>       
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>provider</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.action</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Controller :

```
//The below one returns token.jsp if directly opened in browswer as http://localhost/provider/setToken.action?format=html
@RequestMapping("/provider/setToken")
public String setToken(WebRequest webRequest, Model model, HttpServletRequest request) {
    return "token";
}

//The below one returns json if directly opened in browswer as http://localhost/provider/main.action if format=html is not provided.
@RequestMapping("/provider/main")
public String main(WebRequest webRequest, Model model, HttpServletRequest request) {
    return "main";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It says it right in the link, PPA (Path, Parameter, Accept) strategy

- Path - you're using .action so it doesn't apply
- Parameter - you want to move away from this
- Accept header - so what you're left with is using the Accept header in your requests

Make sure that the ignoreAcceptHeader is not set to true in ContentNegtiationViewResolverBean

Think of the simplest controller method

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/post", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String post() {
    return "main";
}
```

If you send two ajax request with different accept header with eg. jquery

```
    $.ajax({
        headers: {
            Accept: "application/json"
        },
        url: 'http://localhost:8091/post',
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        success: function () {
            console.log('success json');
        },
        error: function () {
            console.log('error');
        }
    });

    $.ajax({
        headers: {
            Accept: "text/html;charset=UTF-8"
        },
        url: 'http://localhost:8091/post',
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: 'text/html',
        success: function () {
            console.log('success');
        },
        error: function () {
            console.log('error');
        }
    })
```

Providing that you have a main.jsp, and that you added JsonView resolver as well in the conf

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver">
   <property name="order" value="1"/>
   <property name="mediaTypes">
        <map>
            <entry key="json" value="application/json"/>
        </map>
    </property>
    <property name="defaultViews">
        <list>
            <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.json.MappingJacksonJsonView"/>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

the response for the two method would be JSON first, text/html second

Comment: After setting headers as @RequestMapping(value = "/provider/test", method = RequestMethod.GET, headers = "Accept:text/html"). I am getting json response as page not found for /provider/test.action

Comment: that way you're setting the you expect the header to be in the request, I'm adding some code to the response

Comment: The code which you have given works for POST method. But how to do it for GET requests (not by changing type to 'GET' in ajax). How to return main.jsp if the url - http://localhost:8091/post is opened in browser?

Comment: changing the controller method type to GET and hitting it with browser directly will show the main.jsp page. Maybe you have some configuration issue, feel free to post your configuration, controller method, and we'll debug it easy

Comment: Added configuration in question. I want to open urls http://localhost/provider/main.action in browswer without adding format=html as query parameter.

Comment: you have <property name="ignoreAcceptHeader" value="true" /> you should set it to false, will add to the answer as well

Comment: tried ignoreAcceptHeader=false also. But it is trying to open a jsp with same name as the url. (ex: if the url is /provider/main, it is trying to render /WEB-INF/provider/provider/main.jsp) even though in controller is returning some other string (name of the jsp file). Is this an expected behavior?

Comment: in fact that means that it its now obeying the Accept header, and no need for format parameter anymore. Regarding that current issue, your configuration is fine, so the only thing that it could be is that you also have "/provider" mapping on the class level, if thats the case methods should be annotated only with e.g. "/main"